# Having trouble getting ID from JSON on Autocomplete

Tags: json, angularjs, bootstrap-typeahead

I have a typeahead that looks like this:

```
<input type="text" class='tk-proxima-nova degreeIn candidateProfile' placeholder="School / Institution"  ng-model="university" typeahead="university.Service_Provider_Name for university in universitySuggest($viewValue)" />
```

it returns JSON that looks similar to this:

```
[{"Service_Provider_ID":133368,"Service_Provider_Name":"Duke University","Service_Provider_Desc":null,"NAICS_Id":1809},{"Service_Provider_ID":196282,"Service_Provider_Name":"Duke University Medical Center","Service_Provider_Desc":null,"NAICS_Id":1809},{"Service_Provider_ID":222220,"Service_Provider_Name":"Duke University Psychology Internship","Service_Provider_Desc":null,"NAICS_Id":1809},{"Service_Provider_ID":223427,"Service_Provider_Name":"Duke University Medical Center Psychology Internship","Service_Provider_Desc":null,"NAICS_Id":1809}]
```

When I select the option from the typeahead it puts the school name in the field as it's supposed to, but is there a way to also set the id to another hidden input so I can send that with my selected data as well.   The ID is what is important here, but the name is needed for viewing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do something like :

```
<input type="text"
  ng-model="selected"
  typeahead-on-select="changeSelect($item)"
  typeahead="university as university.Service_Provider_Name for university in universities | filter:{Service_Provider_Name:$viewValue} " />
```

Here is the <kbd>[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/EmZw6P723FtOl0sNnvUK?p=preview)</kbd>

I've a little indented your code for more clarity.

Comment: The only problem with this is it sets the value when you click as the id and I want the value to show the name of the school but still hold the value of the id

Comment: Since I use `as university.Service_Provider_Name`, the value of `university` will be the *ID*, but your input text will show the name

Comment: Oh sorry I've misunderstood a little your needs, here is an updated [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/EmZw6P723FtOl0sNnvUK?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the comments Apercu gave above regarding the format of the typeahead="..."  ,you need to have a typeahead-input-formatter like this

```
  typeahead-input-formatter="univChosen($model)"

  $scope.univChosen = function(theId) {
         var theItem = jQuery.grep($scope.universities,function(p) {
                                return p.Service_Provider_ID == theId});
    return theItem[0].Service_Provider_Name;
  };
```

I'm assuming here that $scope.universities contains the complete list of all the items in the typeahead choices.  I've used jQuery here to find the matching item but you can just do a for(...) loop if you want. The function returns the string that will actually get displayed, in this case the name.